# How to express "once I had (noun) to do so"

Tags: anglais, pronoms

I just said in conversation:

> Je me suis envolé vers la Suède dès que j’**en** ai eu ***l’âge***, ***les moyens*** et ***le cran***.

I used the pronoun "en" to express the idea of "to do so" in "once I had (noun) to do so", but I wonder if this is how French speakers would commonly express this idea.

Some other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a typical way to express this idea.

Another suggestion:

> ...aussitôt que j'en ai eu l'âge, les moyens et le cran.